# What is difference between fillRect(0,0,0,1) and clearRect()

Tags: javascript, canvas

Is there any difference between:

```
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

and

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
```

Any kind of difference in performance or resulting image or canvas data?

Comment: The alpha channel has only values from 0 to 1, not 255.

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/clearRect): "*`clearRect()` […] sets all pixels in the rectangle […] to **transparent black**.*"

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*(Updated to correspond to OPs changes in question:)* `fillRect()` with `ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)";` will fill the region with opaque pixels, in this case black (note alpha is a normalized value [0,1]).

`clearRect()` does the opposite, "*clearing*" all pixels so that the bitmap becomes transparent (technically the region is filled with black transparent pixels).

`clearRect()` is optimized while `fillRect()` is bound to compositing/blending rules (Porter-Duff) so the former is faster. What this means is that clearRect is free to fill a region directly only based on current transformation, while fillRect *has* to go through the compositing/blending formula whatever that is set to (globalCompositeOperation) in addition.

That is of course in theory - it will depend on browser implementation. Here is a **[simple performance test](http://jsperf.com/canvas-fill-vs-clear)** showing that in Chrome filling is faster than clearing (I am not sure what goes on with Chrome and canvas nowadays), but in Firefox clearing is many times faster than filling, both significantly faster than Chrome:

[image: perfsnap]

In browsers which supports the opacity flag of the context, you can disable alpha if you don't need it, to make canvas respond even faster (the alpha here being blending with the element itself and composition with the browser background). You will see speed improvements in particular the Opera browser, but also Firefox and Chrome support this flag. To disable alpha:

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", {alpha: false});
```

Comment: so fillStyle 0,0,0,1 is closer to what clearRect does?

Comment: @exebook color-wise yes (0,0,0,0), performance-wise no. The color doesn't matter so much as compositing. clearRect can "clear" directly. fillRect has to go through compositing/blending which is more costly.

Comment: Ok, so fillStyle=0,0,0,0+fillRect does the same as clearRect but much slower!

Comment: @exebook depends on browser, Chrome has some "issues" in later version where fill is faster than clear (it used to be opposite for Chrome as well, I am certain they will fix this in the future), but as you can see Firefox is many times faster with clear than fill (you can't technically clear anything with 0 alpha ref. fillRect color (comp mode can change that though), but that is the result with clearRect).

Comment: Update for Chrome 65.0.3325 - `clearRect` is about 10-12% faster.