# Change speed of request animation frame

Tags: javascript, typescript, animation, frontend, requestanimationframe

I have this code to move an image in a canvas from a position to an other one :

```
class Target {
    constructor(img, x_init, y_init, img_width = 100, img_height = 100) {
        this.img = img;
        this.x = x_init;
        this.y = y_init;
        this.img_width = img_width;
        this.img_height = img_height;
    }
    

    get position() {
        return this.x
    }

    move(canvas, x_dest, y_dest) {
        ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        ctx.drawImage(this.img, this.x, this.y, this.img_width, this.img_height);
        if (this.x != x_dest) {
            if (this.x > x_dest) {
                this.x -=1;
            } else {
                this.x +=1;
            }
        }
        if (this.y != y_dest) {
            if (this.y > y_dest) {
                this.y -=1;
            } else {
                this.y +=1;
            }
        }
        if (this.x != x_dest || this.y != y_dest) {
            //setTimeout(this.move.bind(target, canvas, x_dest, y_dest), 0);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(this.move.bind(target, canvas, x_dest, y_dest));
        }
    }

}
```

The thing with this code is : I cannot control the speed, and it's pretty slow...
How could I control the speed and keep this idea of select the arrival position? I found topic about that but I didn't find anything that work in my case, surely because a step of 1 pixel is too small but I don't see How could I make.

[EDIT] Here's what I wanted to do (I have to add a record during 2 seconds when the red circle is shrinking). I did obviously by following pid instructions. Thanks again to him.

```js
(function() {

  function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  var canvas = document.getElementById("calibrator");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

  const points = [{
      "x": 0,
      "y": 0
    },
    {
      "x": canvas.width / 2 - 100,
      "y": 0
    },
    {
      "x": canvas.width - 100,
      "y": 0
    },
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": canvas.height / 2 - 100
    },
    {
      "x": canvas.width / 2 - 100,
      "y": canvas.height / 2 - 100
    },
    {
      "x": canvas.width - 100,
      "y": canvas.height / 2 - 100
    },
    {
      "x": 0,
      "y": canvas.height - 100,
    },
    {
      "x": canvas.width / 2 - 100,
      "y": canvas.height - 100
    },
    {
      "x": canvas.width - 100,
      "y": canvas.height - 100
    }
  ]

  function generateLinear(x0, y0, x1, y1, dt) {
    return (t) => {
      let f0, f1;

      f0 = t >= dt ? 1 : t / dt; // linear interpolation (aka lerp)
      f1 = 1 - f0;

      return {
        "x": f1 * x0 + f0 * x1, // actually is a matrix multiplication
        "y": f1 * y0 + f0 * y1
      };
    };
  }

  function generateShrink(x0, y0, x1, y1, r0, dt) {
    return (t) => {
      var f0 = t >= dt ? 0 : dt - t;
      var f1 = t >= dt ? 1 : dt / t;
      var f2 = 1 - f1;
      return {
        "x": f2 * x0 + f1 * x1,
        "y": f2 * y0 + f1 * y1,
        "r": f0 * r0
      };
    };
  }

  function create_path_circle() {
    var nbPts = points.length;
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nbPts - 1; i++) {
      path.push({
        "duration": 2,
        "segment": generateShrink(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].x, points[i].y, 40, 2)
      });
      path.push({
        "duration": 0.5,
        "segment": generateShrink(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i + 1].x, points[i + 1].y, 0, 0.5)
      });
    }
    path.push({
      "duration": 2,
      "segment": generateShrink(points[nbPts - 1].x, points[nbPts - 1].y, points[nbPts - 1].x, points[nbPts - 1].y, 40, 2)
    })
    return path;
  }

  function create_path_target() {
    var nbPts = points.length;
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < nbPts - 1; i++) {
      path.push({
        "duration": 2,
        "segment": generateLinear(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i].x, points[i].y, 2)
      });
      path.push({
        "duration": 0.5,
        "segment": generateLinear(points[i].x, points[i].y, points[i + 1].x, points[i + 1].y, 0.5)
      });
    }
    path.push({
      "duration": 2,
      "segment": generateLinear(points[nbPts - 1].x, points[nbPts - 1].y, points[nbPts - 1].x, points[nbPts - 1].y, 2)
    })
    return path;
  }

  const path_target = create_path_target();

  const path_circle = create_path_circle();

  function renderImage(img, img_width, img_height) {
    return (pos) => {
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.drawImage(img, pos.x, pos.y, img_width, img_height);
    }
  }

  function renderCircle() {
    return (pos) => {
      ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.arc(pos.x + 50, pos.y + 50, pos.r, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
      ctx.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }

  function generatePath(path) {
    let i, t;
    // fixup timing
    t = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
      path[i].start = t;
      t += path[i].duration;
      path[i].end = t;
    }

    return (t) => {
      while (path.length > 1 && t >= path[0].end) {
        path.shift(); // remove old segments, but leave last one
      }
      return path[0].segment(t - path[0].start); // time corrected
    };
  }


  var base_image = new Image();
  base_image.src = 'https://www.pngkit.com/png/full/17-175027_transparent-crosshair-sniper-scope-reticle.png';

  const sprites = [

    {
      "move": generatePath(path_circle),
      "created": performance.now(),
      "render": renderCircle()
    },
    {
      "move": generatePath(path_target),
      "created": performance.now(),
      "render": renderImage(base_image, 100, 100)
    }
  ];

  const update = () => {
    let now;

    ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

    // put aside so all sprites are drawn for the same ms
    now = performance.now();

    for (var sprite of sprites) {
      sprite.render(sprite.move((now - sprite.created) / 1000));
    }

    window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
  };
  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);

})();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calibration</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <canvas id="calibrator"></canvas>
  <video id="stream"></video>
  <canvas id="picture"></canvas>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="calibration.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

For filming, if we suppose that I have a takeSnapshot() function which returns a picture, I would do:

```
    function film(dt) {
    return (t) => {
        if (t >= dt) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    }
}

function create_video_timeline() {
    var nbPts = points.length;
    var path = [];
    for (var i = 0 ; i < nbPts - 1; i++) {
        path.push(
            {
                "duration": 2,
                "segment": film(2)
            }
        );
        path.push(
            {
                "duration":0.5,
                "segment": film(0)
            }
        );
    }
    path.push(
        {
            "duration": 2,
            "segment": film(2)              
        }
    )
    return path;
}

const video_timeline = create_video_timeline();

function getSnapshot() {
    return (bool) => {
        if (bool) {
            data.push(takepicture());
        } 
    }
}

const sprites = [
    
    {
        "move": generatePath(path_circle),
        "created": performance.now(),
        "render": renderCircle()
    },
    {
        "move": generatePath(path_target),    
        "created": performance.now(),
        "render": renderImage(base_image, 100, 100)
    },
    {
        "render": getSnapshot(),
        "move": generatePath(video_timeline),
        "created": performance.now()
    }
];
```

Comment: I've just added a working example that also shows a slew of other techniques you should look into, especially how to better use a canvas. Hope this helps :)

Comment: I've canged the linear movement to meet our needs and added a "path" movement which uses a composite pattern to construct complex paths. This should answer your first question. About `clearRect()` and `fillRect()` see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30830126/what-is-difference-between-fillrect0-0-0-1-and-clearrect. I have no presumption as to which is better, I just wrote `fillRect()` out of habit. Use `clearRect()` if you prefer :)

Comment: You can also support heterogenous objects in the path array, such as objects that describe not a movement but something else, like "play sound", "play sprite animation" or call an arbitrary trigger function. This opens up to be a full animation framework.

Comment: @pid I add a code snippet which show what I wanted to do. If you have enough time, could you confirm that I did it right ? I wrote one path and one renderer for each element (the target and the circle). And when I want to stop the elemnt for a time, I just update his position with the former one. Are these good practices? Unless they aren't, I'm going to write a film(t) and a sort of "path" for it which would be more like a timeline since I will not render that.

Comment: I think I haven't figured out how to do another action like you said before. Especially when it comes to filming, will I be forced to have the requestanimationframe() fps?

Comment: I think you did well. Those "practices" are exactly how it is supposed to be (renderer, paths, standing still). The idea of an over-arching timeline is good, if you have more than one. If you have only one timeline you can save work and complexity by leaving it as it is.

Comment: About triggering actions from the timeline: say you want to play a sound every time the red circle appears. In the `generatePath()` function add an `if` that checks if a `sound` property is defined in the object, like so: `{ "sound": "shot.ogg" }`. If it is, just play the sound and `shift()`. then process the next object.

Comment: I added "sound" support (search for "sound" and "audio" in the answer). But without a sound file and "interacting with the canvas first" you won't hear anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**: added another movement example (look at cyan square)

To answer your comment about how to get "somewhere" in a fixed amount of time, you can linearize most functions and then solve the equation by fixing the time. This is easy for linear movement but rather difficult for complex cases, like moving along non-linear functions (e.G. a logarithmic spiral).

For a linear movement at constant speed (no acceleration/deceleration) from `(x0, y0)` to `(x1, y1)` in time `dt` you can use linear interpolation:

```js
function generateLinear(x0, y0, x1, y1, dt)
{
  return (t) => {
    let f0, f1;

    f0 = t >= dt ? 1 : t / dt; // linear interpolation (aka lerp)
    f1 = 1 - f;

    return {
      "x": f0 * x0 + f1 * x1, // actually is a matrix multiplication
      "y": f0 * y0 + f1 * y1
    };
  };
}
```

This function can now be used to "assemble" a path. First define the path by generating the segments:

```js
const path = [
  {
    "duration": dt1,
    "segment": generateLinear(x0, y0, x1, y1, dt1)
  },
  {
    "duration": dt2,
    "segment": generateLinear(x1, y1, x2, y2, dt2)
  },
  {
    "duration": dt3,
    "segment": generateLinear(x2, y2, x3, y3, dt3)
  }
];
```

Notice how the total path time will now be handled (using `duration`) and translated into segment local time:

```js
function generatePath(path)
{
  let t;

  // fixup timing
  t = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
  {
    path[i].start = t;
    t += path[i].duration;
    path[i].end = t;
  }

  return (t) => {
    while (path.length > 1 && t >= path[0].end)
    {
      path.shift(); // remove old segments, but leave last one
    }

    return path[0].segment(t - path[0].start); // time corrected
  };
}
```

---

**EDIT**: working example

I just whipped up this working example for you.
Look at how I don't redo the canvas or context and draw on the same over and over. And how the movement does not depend on framerate, it's defined in the lissajous function.

```js
"use strict";

const cvs = document.querySelector("#cvs");
const ctx = cvs.getContext("2d");

function generateLissajous(dx, dy, tx, ty)
{
  return (t) => {
    return {
      "x": 150 + dx * Math.sin(tx * t),
      "y": 75 + dy * Math.cos(ty * t)
    };
  };
}

function generateLinear(x0, y0, x1, y1, dt)
{
  return (t) => {
    let f0, f1;

    f0 = t >= dt ? 1 : t / dt; // linear interpolation (aka lerp)
    f1 = 1 - f0;

    return {
      "x": f1 * x0 + f0 * x1, // actually is a matrix multiplication
      "y": f1 * y0 + f0 * y1
    };
  };
}

function generatePath(path)
{
  let i, t;

  // fixup timing
  t = 0;
  for (i = 0; i < path.length; i++)
  {
    path[i].start = t;
    t += path[i].duration;
    path[i].end = t;
  }

  return (t) => {
    let audio;

    while (path.length > 1 && t >= path[0].end)
    {
      path.shift(); // remove old segments, but leave last one
    }

    if (path[0].hasOwnProperty("sound"))
    {
      audio = new Audio(path[0].sound);
      audio.play();
      delete path[0].sound; // play only once
    }

    return path[0].segment(t - path[0].start); // time corrected
  };
}

function generateRenderer(size, color)
{
  return (pos) => {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(pos.x, pos.y, size, size);
  };
}

const path = [
  {
    "duration": 3,
    "segment": generateLinear(20, 20, 120, 120, 3)
  },
  {
    "sound": "boing.ogg",
    "duration": 3,
    "segment": generateLinear(120, 120, 120, 20, 3)
  },
  {
    "sound": "boing.ogg",
    "duration": 2,
    "segment": generateLinear(120, 20, 20, 120, 2)
  }
];

const sprites = [
  {
    "move": generateLissajous(140, 60, 1.9, 0.3),
    "created": performance.now(),
    "render": generateRenderer(10, "#ff0000")
  },
  {
    "move": generateLissajous(40, 30, 3.23, -1.86),
    "created": performance.now(),
    "render": generateRenderer(15, "#00ff00")
  },
  {
    "move": generateLissajous(80, 50, -2.3, 1.86),
    "created": performance.now(),
    "render": generateRenderer(5, "#0000ff")
  },
  {
    "move": generateLinear(10, 150, 300, 20, 30), // 30 seconds
    "created": performance.now(),
    "render": generateRenderer(15, "#ff00ff")
  },
  {
    "move": generatePath(path),
    "created": performance.now(),
    "render": generateRenderer(25, "#00ffff")
  }
];

const update = () => {
  let now, sprite;
  
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, 300, 150);

  // put aside so all sprites are drawn for the same ms
  now = performance.now(); 
  
  for (sprite of sprites)
  {
    sprite.render(sprite.move((now - sprite.created) / 1000));
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
};

window.requestAnimationFrame(update);
```

```css
canvas
{
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
```

---

You should not rely on `requestAnimtionFrame()` for this kind of movement.

What you should do is this.

1. Have a movement function that is based on realtime (`t`), in this example a Lissajous orbit:

```js
function orbit(t)
{
  return { "x": 34 * Math.sin(t * 0.84), "y": 45 * Math.cos(t * 0.23) };
}
```

Those numerals are just for shows. You can parameterize them and use currying to fixate them and obtain an "orbit()" function like this:

```js
function generateLissajousOrbit(dx, tx, dy, ty)
{
  return (t) => { // this is the orbit function
    return { "x": dx * Math.sin(t * tx), "y": dy * Math.cos(t * ty) };
  };
}
```

This way, you can generate an arbitrary Lissajous orbit:

```js
let movement = generateLissajousOrbit(34, 0.84, 45, 0.23);
```

Obviously, any movement function is valid. The only constraints are:

- invoke with a `t` wich expresses realtime;
- receive an object with `x` and `y` coordinates at time `t`.

Simpler movements should be obvious by now on how to implement. Also note that this way it's extremely easy to plug-in any movement.

2. Determine at which point in the animation/movement you are:

On start put the current realtime milliseconds aside, like so:

```js
let mymovingobject = {
  "started": performance.now(),
  "movement": generateLissajousOrbit(34, 0.84, 45, 0.23)
};
```

To get the `x` and `y` at any given time, you can now do as follows:

```js
let now = performance.now();
let pos = mymovingobject.movement(now - mymovingobject.started);

// pos.x and pos.y contain the current coordinates
```

You will get a refresh (animation frame) independent movement that solely depends on realtime, which is your subjective perception space.

If the machine has a hickup or the refresh rate changes for any reason (user has just recalibrated the monitor, moved the window across desktops from a 120 Hz to a 60 Hz monitor, or whatever) .... the movement will still be realtime bound and completely independent of frame rate.

3. now you can poll position at any given time and use it for rendering

In the function that handles `requestAnimationFrame()`, you simply poll the position as shown above and then draw the object at `pos.x` and `pos.y`, without ever thinking about what the actual refresh rate is.

You can also skip frames to reduce frame rate and let the user decide the frequency by counting frames, like so:

```js
let frame = 0;

function requestAnimationFrameHandler()
{
  if (frame % 2 === 0)
  {
    window.requestAnimationFrame();
    return; // quick bail-out for this frame, see you next time!
  }

  // update canvas at half framerate
}
```

Being able to reduce framerate is especially important today because of high frequency monitors. Your app would jump from 60 pixel/second to 120 pixel/second just by changing monitors. This is not what you want.

The `requestAnimationFrame()` facility looks like a panacea for smooth scrolling, but the truth is you bind yourself to the hardware constraints which are completely unknown (think about modern monitors in 2035... who knows how they will be).

This technique separates physical frame frequency from logical (gameplay) speed requirements.

Hope that makes sense somehow.

Comment: If I understood well; I have to find t(x) and t(y) where t(x)/t(y) is the time at which the element is in x/y. Then in the while I already wrote I will have to update the position with x = x+ t(x) ?

Comment: It's better t(x) is not a delta but the absolute position. This way, t2 does not depend on t1. You can jump from t1 to t9 or backwards from t8 to t6 and so on... if you have t(x) as a delta, then you're losing all these qualities.

Comment: So I need x(t). Thanks for your explaination. It's really smart! Thanks for all the time you spend for me.
I'm going to try for my case and let you know if it works. If it works I will put your answer as the one :)

Comment: Ok so I remain with 2 questions :

I remain with two questions:
- In my case, I want my image to go in (x1, y1) in two seconds, do a thing (independant of the canvas), then in (x2, y2) in two seconds, do a thing etc... How can I do that since I will need various linear function for only one element ?
- In your example (which is great for the community, thanks), are you sure it's better overwriting the canvas instead of erasing it?

Comment: Very good answer. Minor nits: in the last snippet it should be `window.requestAnimationFrame( requestAnimationFrameHandler )`, it's currently missing the function, and instead of simply "counting" the number of passed frames, maybe a more useful metric would be to check how long has passed since the last frame. One may want to throttle a 240Hz monitor to 60FPS but they will probably not want to throttle a 60Hz one to 15FPS ;-) Though it might become a lot more complex to measure, [One can't assume a fixed rate in neither directions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66323325/66343946).

Comment: @pid Thanks for your answer. It's really beautiful code as I like. Now I have everything in my hands to stpe forward :)

Comment: @Kaiido thank you and I agree, there's plenty of room for improvement :)

Comment: @PaulSerre this style of code is "class-less" and functional. Not everybody likes it, but I've found *huge* advantages in designing mid-size apps this way. For larger or team-based apps it's probably not good because comunication between team members is very important, and this code style does not express every intrinsic clearly. But I agree, it has a flowing aesthetic that can be "beautiful". Thank you!